# Detect duplicate videos from YouTube

Tags: algorithm, matlab, video, image-processing, youtube

In consideration to my M.tech Project
I want to know if there is any algorithm to detect duplicate videos from youtube.
For example (here are links of two videos):

[random user upload](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozPaBYDD184)

[upload by official channel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkF0_lbBmjU)

Amongst these second is official video and T-series has it's copyright.

Is youtube officially doing something to remove duplicate videos from youtube?
Not only videos, there exists duplicate youtube channels also.
Sometimes the original video has less number of views than that of pirated version.

So, while searching found [this](http://www.iiitd.edu.in/%7Eashish/SWATI-MTECH-THESIS-PRESENTATION-02-APRIL.pdf)
(see page number [49] of pdf)

**What I learnt from the given link**

Original vs copyright infringed video detection Classifier is used.
Given a query, firstly top k search results are being retrieved.Thereafter three parameters are used to classify the videos

1. Number of subscribers
2. user profile
3. username popularity

and on the basis of these parameters, original video is identified as described in the link.

**EDIT 1:**

There are basically two different objectives

- To identify original video with the above method
- To eliminate the duplicate videos

obviously identifying original video is easier than finding out all the duplicate videos.
So i preferred to first find out the original video.

Approach which i can think till now
to improve the accuracy:

- We can first find out the original videos with above method
- And then use the most popular publicized frames(may be multiple) of that video to search on google image. This method therefore retrieves the list of duplicate videos in google image search results.

After getting these duplicate videos, we can once again check frame by frame and reach a level of satisfaction(yes retrieved videos were "exact or "almost" duplicate copy of original video)

Will this approach work?
if not, is there any better algorithm, to improve upon the given method?

**Please write in the comments section if i am unable to explain my approach clearly.
I will soon add some more details.**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Are you saying that, given some number of random videos, you want to determine which are duplicates and, of the duplicates, which is the original video?

Comment: @JimMischel: yes exactly i want to do this and
currently i am thinking of only youtube videos.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently hacked together a [small tool for that purpose](https://github.com/Eierkopp/viddup). It's still work in progress but usually pretty accurate. The idea is to simply compare time between brightness maxima in the center of the video. Therefore it should work with different resolutions, frame rates and rotation of the video. 
ffmpeg is used for decoding, imageio as bridge to python, numpy/scipy for maxima computation and some k-nearest-neighbor library (annoy, cyflann, hnsw) for comparison.

At the moment it's not polished at all so you should know a little python to run it or simply copy the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Me too had the same problem.. So wrote a program myself..

Problem is I had videos of various formats and resolution.. So needed to take hash of each video frame and compare.

https://github.com/gklc811/duplicate_video_finder

you can just change the directories at top and you are good to go..

```
from os import path, walk, makedirs, rename
from time import clock
from imagehash import average_hash
from PIL import Image
from cv2 import VideoCapture, CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT, CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, CAP_PROP_FPS
from json import dump, load
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

input_vid_dir = r'C:\Users\gokul\Documents\data\\'
json_dir = r'C:\Users\gokul\Documents\db\\'
analyzed_dir = r'C:\Users\gokul\Documents\analyzed\\'
duplicate_dir = r'C:\Users\gokul\Documents\duplicate\\'

if not path.exists(json_dir):
    makedirs(json_dir)

if not path.exists(analyzed_dir):
    makedirs(analyzed_dir)

if not path.exists(duplicate_dir):
    makedirs(duplicate_dir)


def write_to_json(filename, data):
    file_full_path = json_dir + filename + ".json"
    with open(file_full_path, 'w') as file_pointer:
        dump(data, file_pointer)
    return


def video_to_json(filename):
    file_full_path = input_vid_dir + filename
    start = clock()
    size = round(path.getsize(file_full_path) / 1024 / 1024, 2)
    video_pointer = VideoCapture(file_full_path)
    frame_count = int(VideoCapture.get(video_pointer, int(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)))
    width = int(VideoCapture.get(video_pointer, int(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)))
    height = int(VideoCapture.get(video_pointer, int(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
    fps = int(VideoCapture.get(video_pointer, int(CAP_PROP_FPS)))
    success, image = video_pointer.read()
    video_hash = {}
    while success:
        frame_hash = average_hash(Image.fromarray(image))
        video_hash[str(frame_hash)] = filename
        success, image = video_pointer.read()
    stop = clock()
    time_taken = stop - start
    print("Time taken for ", file_full_path, " is : ", time_taken)
    data_dict = dict()
    data_dict['size'] = size
    data_dict['time_taken'] = time_taken
    data_dict['fps'] = fps
    data_dict['height'] = height
    data_dict['width'] = width
    data_dict['frame_count'] = frame_count
    data_dict['filename'] = filename
    data_dict['video_hash'] = video_hash
    write_to_json(filename, data_dict)
    return


def multiprocess_video_to_json():
    files = next(walk(input_vid_dir))[2]
    processes = cpu_count()
    print(processes)
    pool = Pool(processes)
    start = clock()
    pool.starmap_async(video_to_json, zip(files))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    stop = clock()
    print("Time Taken : ", stop - start)


def key_with_max_val(d):
    max_value = 0
    required_key = ""
    for k in d:
        if d[k] > max_value:
            max_value = d[k]
            required_key = k
    return required_key


def duplicate_analyzer():
    files = next(walk(json_dir))[2]
    data_dict = {}
    for file in files:
        filename = json_dir + file
        with open(filename) as f:
            data = load(f)
        video_hash = data['video_hash']
        count = 0
        duplicate_file_dict = dict()
        for key in video_hash:
            count += 1
            if key in data_dict:
                if data_dict[key] in duplicate_file_dict:
                    duplicate_file_dict[data_dict[key]] = duplicate_file_dict[data_dict[key]] + 1
                else:
                    duplicate_file_dict[data_dict[key]] = 1
            else:
                data_dict[key] = video_hash[key]
        if duplicate_file_dict:
            duplicate_file = key_with_max_val(duplicate_file_dict)
            duplicate_percentage = ((duplicate_file_dict[duplicate_file] / count) * 100)
            if duplicate_percentage > 50:
                file = file[:-5]
                print(file, " is dup of ", duplicate_file)
                src = analyzed_dir + file
                tgt = duplicate_dir + file
                if path.exists(src):
                    rename(src, tgt)
                # else:
                #     print("File already moved")


def mv_analyzed_file():
    files = next(walk(json_dir))[2]
    for filename in files:
        filename = filename[:-5]
        src = input_vid_dir + filename
        tgt = analyzed_dir + filename
        if path.exists(src):
            rename(src, tgt)
        # else:
        #     print("File already moved")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mv_analyzed_file()
    multiprocess_video_to_json()
    mv_analyzed_file()
    duplicate_analyzer()
```